# C/c: modding out an object

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $\mathbf{C}$ and some object $c \in \mathbf{C}$, what's the meaning of $\mathbf{C}/c$?

I know that for a congruence relation $R$ on $\mathbf{C}$, the expression $\mathbf{C}/R$ denotes the *quotient category* of equivalence classes. But I don't know how to similarly "mod out" an object $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{C}/c$ denotes a **slice category** or **over category** of arrows pointing to $c$. On nLab it is [defined](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category) like so:

> The **slice category** or **over category** $\mathbf{C}/c$ of a category $\mathbf{C}$ over an object $c \in \mathbf{C}$ has
>
> - objects that are all arrows $f \in \mathbf{C}$ such that $cod(f) = c$, and
> - morphisms $g: X \to X' \in \mathbf{C}$ from $f:X \to c$ to $f': X' \to c$ such that $f' \circ g = f$.
>
> $$
>   C/c
>   =
>   \left\lbrace
>     \array{
>        X &&\stackrel{g}{\to}&& X'
>        \\
>        & {}_f \searrow && \swarrow_{f'}
>        \\   
>        && c
>     }
>   \right\rbrace
> $$

Slice categories ($\mathbf{C}/c$) don't seem to have a very obvious relation to quotient categories ($\mathbf{C}/R$); they just use the same syntax. The alternative syntax $\mathbf{C} \downarrow c$ avoids this potential confusion.

There is also the dual notion of a [*coslice category*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/under+category) or *under category* of arrows pointing away from $c$, denoted $c/\mathbf{C}$ or $c \downarrow \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how this is similar to a quotient? I would have expected that if the category was for example additive, then this notation would mean killing off all morphisms through the given object.

Comment: I strongly prefer the notations $\mathbf{C} \downarrow C$ and $C \downarrow \mathbf{C}$ for slice and coslice, respectively. It distinguishes it from a quotient category and it's a useful mnemonic for the direction of the arrow-objects (from the category's objects to the distinguished object)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It isn't really similar to a quotient in the sense of abstract algebra, but more in the sense of arithmetic: here is a thing being placed over another thing. But there's no formal interpretation of slicing as division.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Then why have people chosen this notation? That just seems like a recipe for confusion.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft There's no real opportunity for ambiguity here, as a general category doesn't admit any reasonable sense of modding out by an object, and I explained the intuition of "over." I think it's generally true in mathematics that a field's characteristic notations can be uninterpretable at first sight-they're meant as mnemonics, not as carriers of meaning in their own right. That said, I agree with Larry on this one.

Comment: I've added a note that there doesn't seem to be an "obvious" relation between slice categories and quotient categories. I hope this isn't too far off.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - Mathematics is way too big not to re-use symbols. Even within category theory some notations end up being reused for multiple purposes. The only antidote for this is to become familiar with an area's conventions and learn to spot context clues.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It certainly comes from e.g. algebraic geometry where it is very common to speak about, for example, "a scheme **over** $X$" which are schemes equipped with a map to $X$. The category of such schemes is $\mathsf{Sch} / X$, read "schemes over $X$"... Just like you would read $1/2$ as "1 over 2". In any case I think a common notation is actually $\mathsf{C}_{/X}$ which eliminates confusion.